# How to use type from other module

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

JSDoc under VS Code: How to use type from other module? In the example below, how to declare `foo(ta)`?

ma.js (CommonJS)

```
class TA {...}

module.exports = { makeTA: () => new TA, };
```

mb.js (CommonJS)

```
const ma = require('./ma');

foo(ma.makeTA());

/** @param {???} ta */ // want to use TA from ma
function foo(ta) {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use import("./ma") as the type. But you also have to export the class you want to use as the type.

ma.js

```js
class TA { }

module.exports = { makeTA: () => new TA, TA };
```

mb.js

```js
/** @param {import("./ma").TA} ta */
function foo(ta) {...}
```

Like this "ta" will be typed as the instance of the class from the other file.

Comment: Well, the requirement of export the class/type is horrible (or I'll call it non-sense).

Comment: @user2771324 It doesn't know which symbols to expose to other files if they are not exported. If they aren't exported, they aren't expected to be used externally.
At least in typescript you can export and import types only, but the same rule applies: It must be exported.